# New column tracking duplicate matches in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with >200 columns. I'm interested in strings that repeat based on two columns, **Title** and **Date**.

Input:

```
Title                       Date        Country            
This is                     2007           Afghanistan        
a test to                   1999           Switzerland        
find country                2004           Sweden            
names that share            1987           Algeria            
certain titles.             2004           Afghanistan        
a test to                   1999           Albania            
a test to                   1999           Afghanistan        
names that share            1987           Afghanistan        
a test to                   2010           Algeria
```

Specifically, whenever row *i*'s **Title** AND **Date**  match row *j*'s, I'd like to record all the unique values that show up in a third column, **Country**.

So for example: consider rows where `Title=="a test to" & Date==1999`. The following countries appear in all the matches: Albania, Afghanistan, Switzerland. Therefore, for every row with a match, we'd enter `Albania, Afghanistan, Switzerland` (but not `Algeria` etc).

Expected output:

```
Title                       Date        Country            Total_Countries
This is                     2007           Afghanistan        Afghanistan
a test to                   1999           Switzerland        Albania, Afghanistan, Switzerland
find country                2004           Sweden             Sweden
names that share            1987           Algeria            Algeria, Afghanistan
certain titles.             2004           Afghanistan        Afghanistan
a test to                   1999           Albania            Albania, Afghanistan, Switzerland
a test to                   1999           Afghanistan        Albania, Afghanistan, Switzerland
names that share            1987           Afghanistan        Algeria, Afghanistan
a test to                   2010           Algeria            Algeria
```

To me it looks like a more complicated version of this question: [Create new column with matched values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73681969/create-new-column-with-matched-values-in-r)

My primitive solution was something like

```
x <- aggregate(Country ~ Title + Date, df, FUN = paste, collapse=", ")
names(x)[3] <- "Total_Countries"
df <- merge(df, x, all.x=T)
```

but this does not produce the right results. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear. The output is in the fourth column, "Total_Countries". I edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: It does produce the right results. Only that the rows are reordered. Note that you could turn it to the original order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have the columns Title, Date, and Country, from your question I believe you are trying to create the column Total_Countries.

In order to do that you can use tidyverse group_by and summarise:

```
library(tidyverse)
your_df %>%
  group_by(Title, Date) %>%
  mutate(Total_Countries = toString(unique(Country))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: This definitely solved the first part of my problem! I have trouble when trying to recombine with the other 197 columns though. Can you please help me by adding a merge step?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to leave those columns out to begin with? If you leave them in, I will update my answer with a way to do this without altering other columns. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ideally yes they would be left in. I should have been clearer.

Comment: No worries, glad it worked. I added ungroup() as a final call just so you don't run into grouping issues downstream.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `mutate` after grouping

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0
df %>% 
   mutate(Total_Countries = toString(sort(unique(Country))),
    .by = c(Title, Date))
```

-output

```
       Title Date     Country                   Total_Countries
1          This is 2007 Afghanistan                       Afghanistan
2        a test to 1999 Switzerland Afghanistan, Albania, Switzerland
3     find country 2004      Sweden                            Sweden
4 names that share 1987     Algeria              Afghanistan, Algeria
5  certain titles. 2004 Afghanistan                       Afghanistan
6        a test to 1999     Albania Afghanistan, Albania, Switzerland
7        a test to 1999 Afghanistan Afghanistan, Albania, Switzerland
8 names that share 1987 Afghanistan              Afghanistan, Algeria
9        a test to 2010     Algeria                           Algeria
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Title = c("This is", "a test to", "find country", 
"names that share", "certain titles.", "a test to", "a test to", 
"names that share", "a test to"), Date = c(2007L, 1999L, 2004L, 
1987L, 2004L, 1999L, 1999L, 1987L, 2010L), Country = c("Afghanistan", 
"Switzerland", "Sweden", "Algeria", "Afghanistan", "Albania", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Algeria")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: This threw an error. Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `.by = c(Title, Date)`.
✖ `.by` must be size 9 or 1, not 18.

Comment: @beddotcom You must have `dplyr version >=1.1.0`  Note that in your case, you are using an older version Thats why you have an error as it is trying to create a columnknown as `.by` instead of grouping

Answer (score 2):

Note that your result is correct. The ordering is often different and the `sort` argument in `merge` does not help that much. To maintain the ordering, you could do the following:

```
x <- aggregate(cbind(Total_Countries = Country)~., unique(df), toString)
by_cols <- c("Title", "Date")
index <- match(interaction(df[by_cols]), interaction(x[by_cols]))
data.frame(df, x[index, setdiff(names(x), by_cols), drop = FALSE], row.names = NULL)

             Title Date     Country                   Total_Countries
1          This is 2007 Afghanistan                       Afghanistan
2        a test to 1999 Switzerland Switzerland, Albania, Afghanistan
3     find country 2004      Sweden                            Sweden
4 names that share 1987     Algeria              Algeria, Afghanistan
5  certain titles. 2004 Afghanistan                       Afghanistan
6        a test to 1999     Albania Switzerland, Albania, Afghanistan
7        a test to 1999 Afghanistan Switzerland, Albania, Afghanistan
8 names that share 1987 Afghanistan              Algeria, Afghanistan
9        a test to 2010     Algeria                           Algeria
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess it wasn't a very good MWE, because it does not work on my real data. Good explanation though.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(Title = c("This is", "a test to", "find country", 
                               "names that share", "certain titles.", "a test to", "a test to", 
                               "names that share", "a test to"), Date = c(2007L, 1999L, 2004L, 1987L, 2004L, 1999L, 1999L, 1987L, 2010L), Country = c("Afghanistan", "Switzerland", "Sweden", "Algeria", "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Algeria")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
df %>% 
  group_by(Title, Date) %>% 
  summarize(Total_Countries = paste(Country, collapse = ", "))

#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Title'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#> # Groups:   Title [5]
#>   Title             Date Total_Countries                  
#>   <chr>            <int> <chr>                            
#> 1 This is           2007 Afghanistan                      
#> 2 a test to         1999 Switzerland, Albania, Afghanistan
#> 3 a test to         2010 Algeria                          
#> 4 certain titles.   2004 Afghanistan                      
#> 5 find country      2004 Sweden                           
#> 6 names that share  1987 Algeria, Afghanistan
```